# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for MvcSiteMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSiteMapProvider MVC5 with my web application and inside of my _Layout.cshtml file I am using:

```
@if (Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap.CurrentNode != Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap.RootNode)
    {
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
    }
```

But the Intellisence is throwing this error:

```
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for MvcSiteMap
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @StevenV Ofcourse that has fixed the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html
```

Fixed by adding this to the top of the view as said by

@StevenV

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing a using statement. Try adding `@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html` to the top of the view.

If you're going to use it often, think about adding the namespace to the `<namespaces>` section under `<system.web.webPages.razor>` in the Views\Web.config. That will make it available on all Razor views inside that folder without the need of an `using` statement on each individual view.

Answer (score 4):

The namespaces that @Steven V mentioned are automatically added to the `Views\Web.config` file during installation of the NuGet package.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

However, Visual Studio intellisense requires a recompile of the project before it picks them up. There is no need to add a `@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html` statement to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the MvcSiteMap Provider.

You can do this from the Package Manger Console with the following command:

```
Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5
```

Then at the top of the razor add:

```
@using MvcSiteMapProvider
```